# Python String Manipulation Concerns

Tags: python, string

Learning Python here:  I am simply trying to switch characters in a string.  Example:  'A' to 'C'.  The string just isn't doing anything.  Here is what I have so far:

```
import string
dummy = "beans"
for i in xrange(len(dummy)):
    chr(ord(dummy[i])+5)
print(dummy)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that strings are immutable, so you will need to re-assign your original string. You can try something along these lines:

```
dummy = "beans"
newdummy = ""
for i in xrange(len(dummy)):
    newdummy += chr(ord(dummy[i])+5)
dummy = newdummy
print(dummy)
```

---

This would be a more *Pythonic* approach:

```
dummy = ''.join(chr(ord(c) + 5) for c in dummy)
print(dummy)
```

Comment: Thank you, I am used to C++ so Python seems a bit... different :)

Comment: @AlexanderGardner Yep glad I could help :-) Yea Python offers *many* utilities that are not available in languages like C++, so it takes time to get used to. Anyway, don't forget to accept an answer!

Answer (score 1):

the string.maketrans should be more elegant here:

```
import string

src = string.ascii_letters
dst = string.ascii_letters[5:] + string.ascii_letters[:5]
trans = string.maketrans(src, dst)
new_dummy = dummy.translate(trans)
```

for details, please reference the doc of string.maketrans.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in python are immutable. This means that you cannot change them, so you'll have to reassign the variable to a new string instead.

Here's an example:

```
import string
dummy = "beans"
for i in xrange(len(dummy)):
    dummy = dummy[:i] + chr(ord(dummy[i])+5) + dummy[i+1:]
print(dummy)
```

Or a shorter way:

```
dummy = "beans"
dummy = "".join([chr(ord(c)+5) for c in dummy])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by doing:

```
mystring="hello"
newstring=""
for x in range(len(mystring)):
    newstring+=chr(ord(mystring[x])+5)
```

however, please know that if you do this, and you get up to 251 in the ASCII value, adding 5 will throw an error, so you should check whatever value you are using with an if statement like:

```
if ord(character)+value<255:
    ##your ok
else:
    ##uh oh...
```